# Why HttpContext.Current.Session["value"].ToString() gives null value inside App_Code class file, Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Here Scenario is HttpContext.Current.Session["value"].ToString() gives null value, even have already set session value when user login.

**My webconfig**

```
<sessionState timeout="40" mode="InProc"/>
```

**My global.asax**

```
   void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
       // Code that runs when a new session is started
       Session["EmployeeId"] = "";
       this.Session["DomainName"] = "";
    }
```

**In my Defaultpage.asppx.cs**

`Emp_grade empgrd = new Emp_grade();` gives  Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public partial class EmpGrade : System.Web.UI.Page
{

   //here am getting error(The type initializer for 'Emp_grade' threw an exception)
   // stack error message  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   Emp_grade empgrd = new Emp_grade(); 

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      logic code...
      Datatable dt= empgrd.EmpRecord();
    }
}
```

In my `App_Code folder` i have class file `Emp_grade.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.SessionState;

public class Emp_grade  
{       
    public Emp_grade()
    {
        //TODO: Add constructor logic here
    }

    static string getConnection = HttpContext.Current.Session["DomainName"].ToString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[getConnection].ConnectionString);

     public DataTable EmpRecord()
    {
       logic code
    }
 }
```

**My login page:**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
    //set some value
     Session["DomainName"] = domainname;
    }
```

**ScreenShot(Debugging)**
[image]

Comment: So... You're trying to get the value off the session tag after assigning a value to it?

Comment: does your connection string work?

Comment: connectionstring works,only if i get the getConnection not null values

Comment: @NewAmbition: yes i want to retrieve that session["domainame"] value

Comment: @satindersingh would `string domainName = Session["domainname"].ToString()` not work?

Comment: @Jodrell: if i set hardcode value to string getConnection, then is work fine, but i need to get from session["domainname"]. Much appretiatable if any other way to accomplish this task

Comment: @NewAmbition: `string domainName = Session["domainname"].ToString()` gives this error **The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably refactor a bit. This:

```
static string getConnection = HttpContext.Current.Session["DomainName"].ToString();
```

is a static field with an initializer. It will run **once**, and keep whatever value it got until the application is restarted. And it will run at a time that is not very well defined, it is only guranteed that it will run sometime before it is first accessed.

This means that it may well run at a time when no `HttpContext` is present (like **Dan Puzey** wrote) which will cause an exception to be thrown. Any subsequent attempt to access it will (to the best of my knowledge) result in the same Exception being thrown.

But keep in mind that it is only fetched once, so even if the initializer were to succeed and find a value, that value will be used for all subsequent uses of `getConnection`. It will not be fetched anew for each different user.

To fix that, you could wrap it in an instance method:

```
private string GetDomainName()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Session["DomainName"].ToString();
}
SqlConnection conn = null;
```

and then initialize `conn` in the constructor:

```
public Emp_grade()         
{         
    conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[GetDomainName()].ConnectionString);
}
```

Please also note the since this class is initializing and storing a `SqlConnection` (which is `IDisposable`), your class should also implement the `IDisposable` interface. For background information about implementing `IDisposable`, see for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface/538238#538238).

**EDIT**: The screenshot shows that the `HttpContext.Current.Session` is returning null.

The reason is this line:

```
Emp_grade empgrd = new Emp_grade();
```

This is declaring an instance member in the Page class, with an initializer. The initializer is run very early in the request pipeline, so at the point when it runs the Session is not yet present in the context.

Change to:

```
Emp_grade empgrd = null;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  empgrd = new Emp_grade();
  Datatable dt = empgrd.EmpRecord(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but still same error **System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** at `return HttpContext.Current.Session["DomainName"].ToString();`

Comment: @satindersingh Then you must figure out which object is null on that line. It could be that `HttpContext.Current` is null, or `HttpContext.Current.Session` is null or simply that there is nothing in the Session with the key `DomainName`. To find out which, put a break point on the line and then when the breakpoint is hit, hover your mouse over each in turn and see what the tooltip shows. Also check the call stack to see where the class is being newed up.

Comment: pls check the screenshot, have updated my question, hope its helps

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing `.Session["DomainName"]` in a constructor for a static field.  That will potentially run before any of your other code does.  Quite possibly it will run outside of any `HttpContext` at all, because chances are it'll run as the application initialised, before the first request is processed.

I suspect that making `getConnection` non-static will fix the problem.

Comment: I also suspect that creating a SQL connection in every instance of Emp_grade is not an ideal solution.

Comment: getConnection non-static will fix the problem gives error " A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Emp_grade.getConnection'"

Comment: @satindersingh: You should move your initialisation to the constructor instead, then.